# Python 3. Trying to create a dictionary using 3 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a school project and I'm have difficulties on the very end of my program.

```
def index_district():
  dist = input("Please enter district: ")
  district=[dist]
  candidates = []
  var1 = 1
  while var1:
    var1 += 1
    candidates_names = input('Enter name of candidate for the district.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_names == '':
        break
    candidates.append(candidates_names)

  votes = []
  var2 = 1
  while var2:
    var2 += 1
    candidates_votes = input('Enter number of votes for the district.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_votes == '':
        break
    votes.append(candidates_votes)

  parties = []
  var3 = 1
  while var3:
    var3 += 1
    candidates_parties = input('Enter parties for the district.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_parties == '':
        break
    parties.append(candidates_parties)



  canidate_parties = dict(zip(parties, candidates))
  party_votes = dict(zip(parties, votes))
  dic = dict(zip(district, zip(canidate_parties, party_votes)))
  print(dic)

index_district()
```

And my output is

```
Please enter district: qwe
Enter name of candidate for the district.  Hit enter again to end  as
Enter name of candidate for the district.  Hit enter again to end  ds
Enter name of candidate for the district.  Hit enter again to end  xc
Enter name of candidate for the district.  Hit enter again to end  
Enter number of votes for the district.  Hit enter again to end  123
Enter number of votes for the district.  Hit enter again to end  234
Enter number of votes for the district.  Hit enter again to end  345
Enter number of votes for the district.  Hit enter again to end  
Enter parties for the district.  Hit enter again to end  rrr
Enter parties for the district.  Hit enter again to end  eee
Enter parties for the district.  Hit enter again to end  www
Enter parties for the district.  Hit enter again to end  
{'qwe': ('rrr', 'rrr')}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

however my end code is supposed to look something like this (Im using the example provided by the prof):

```
{’Name ’: ’Humboldt ’,
’Candidates ’: {’LIB ’: ’Elliott ’, ’NDP ’: ’Angela ’, ’SK ’: ’Mr. Robot ’}, 
’Votes ’: {’LIB ’: 2732 , ’NDP ’: 101 , ’SK ’: 370}
}
```

What im not understanding is how to make the lists work in the fashion i want them to. Any help would be appreciated.

A smaller part of the program works fine:

```
def create_mapping():

 keys = []
 i = 0
 while 1:
     i += 1
     item = input('Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  ' )
     if item == '':
         break
     keys.append(item)

 votes = []
 x = 0
 while 1:
     x += 1
     partyvotes = input('Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  ')
     if partyvotes == '':
         break
     votes.append(partyvotes)

 dic = dict(zip(keys, votes))
 length = len(keys)

 print (dic)

create_mapping()
```

which gives me the output of

```
Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  red
Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  blue
Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  green
Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  
Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  123
Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  234
Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  345
Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  
{'red': '123', 'blue': '234', 'green': '345'}
```

But why isnt that going over as well in the bigger program?

Comment: this is not an error.. it says process done.. there is nothing to proceed further

Comment: @hunteke When the program is set to make only lists it works fine, its the end part of making a dictionary that i get lost in.  for example i dont know why it reads the first parties for the district twice

Answer (score 0):

It is not error. Just you did not use proper method to generate your output.

I'm suggesting you follow your code line by line:

```
canidate_parties = dict(zip(parties, candidates))
# => {'rrr': 'as', 'eee': 'ds', 'www': 'xc'}

party_votes = dict(zip(parties, votes))
# => {'rrr': 123, 'eee': 234, 'www': 345}

# This is wrong part
dic = dict(zip(district, zip(canidate_parties, party_votes)))
# zip(canidate_parties, party_votes)
# => [('rrr', 'rrr'), ('eee', 'eee'), ('www', 'www')]
# zip(district, zip(canidate_parties, party_votes)))
# => [('qwe', ('rrr', 'rrr'))]
# dict(zip(district, zip(canidate_parties, party_votes))))
# => {'qwe': ('rrr', 'rrr')}
```

I think you can get a point. Learning more about `dict()` and `zip()` will help you. If you want your output, you need to change `dic = ...` line.